# Admin Server should not serve Store pages

Tags: magento

I have a multi-server single-store Magento setup as follows:

- *n* webservers behind a loadbalancer at `www.mydomain.com`
- Admin server serving the admin panel answering at `admin.mydomain.com`

The setup works fine, and when I go to `www.mydomain.com/admin` I will ultimately be redirected to `admin.mydomain.com/index.php/admin`. My problem is that if you go to `admin.mydomain.com/store-page.html` where `store-page.html` is a product, category, or other page, then the page is served. I don't want this to happen for both SEO reasons (we discovered this because someone posted links to our store on the admin server) and load balancing reasons. Is there a way in Magento to tell a specific server not to serve store pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lot of possibilities:

1. protect the admin with http basic authentication
2. make a mod_rewrite rule to redirect all requests to admin page
3. protect the admin domain with ip access rules etc